# Swagger class property decoration

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-codegen

In .NET core project, we have class, for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Items {get;set;}
}
```

In swagger model definition we want that Items property has definition of type string array and not string, how to acomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass arrayof strings in a uri your controller should be something like below.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStringsValues([FromUri]List<string> s){
   return s;
}
```